# How many GB data can be upload per Team Site on SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any limit on data size to be uploaded on a Team site? How many GB data can be upload per Team Site on SharePoint online?

Comment: I hope you have gone through this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-limits-and-quotas-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things to be noted.

- SharePoint Online Team Sites quota size is 25 TB.it is as per your plan.
- You can upload 15gb file.
- You Can also manage the quota of site collection from admin portal.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-site-collection-storage-limits-77389c2c-8e7e-4b16-ab97-1c7103784b08

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-limits-and-quotas-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc351043094

Answer (score 0):

Individual site limits can be set through the SP admin. I believe the absolute upper limit for Office 365 tenents is 1 terabyte for the entire site collection. Note there is a limit on number of files per site.